# How to overlap divs in a column?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope

i got a table column and put dynamically some divs in it. The divs a child of a container-div, so they can positioned absolute in it.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100px">
  <div id="div1" style="position:absolute;top:50px;height:100px;width:100px"></div>
  <div id="div2" style="position:absolute;top:50px;height:100px;width:100px"></div>
</div>
```

The first problem here is, that div2 covers div1. So div1 need width of 50px, div2 also. And div2 must get left: 50px. Is there a way to check if a div overlay an other div? Or is there any jQuery plugin that fit all divs in the column?

Here is an example what i need. Its from google calendar:

[image: example]

Edit:
Ok at the moment i can do these with some JavaScript:

[image]

But i need these:
[image]

Appointment 7 and 6 must swicht. So they fit the empty spaces. Can i do these with isotope?

EDIT: may sort by datetime with isotope and set the css top property by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the plugin like:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: masonry dont change the divs width to fit in column. but thats the function i need

Comment: @thomas, another jquery plungin:　`http://isotope.metafizzy.co/`　also rearrange the div position automaticlly.

Answer (score 0):

use css property called Z-index. Z-index manage them as a layer. This will allow you to overlapping divs on one another.

Comment: I know z-index, but it divs with same size covers each other.